# Real time iot dashboard using Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, iot, dashboard, particle-photon

I am looking to build a quick and dirty IoT prototype. I am using particle photons to stream sensor information to the Google Cloud Platform. Inside GCP, I have Pub/Sub->Cloud Functions->BigQuery as my architecture.

I am now looking to build a live/real-time dashboard with the data coming in. 
1. What would be the easiest tool to achieve this? (Google Data Studio won't work as it only produces reports, I need an update every few seconds)?
2. Would it be wise to create a web app and query my bigquery database every few seconds? I am given to understand this can c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Cloud Platform Data Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311655/google-cloud-platform-data-display)

Comment: Just a quick Q: Are you massaging the data coming in from the device in the cloud function? Or are you just passing it through into BigQuery? DataFlow provides a template to push from Pub/Sub to BigQuery.

Comment: @GabeWeiss Currently not massaging any of the data coming in but would like to have that flexibility for later. My question is on how I can get a live dashboard using the data being loaded onto bigquery

Comment: Live dashboard on BigQuery is potentially very expensive, because a live dashboard would have to constantly rescan your data. So it depends on how big your data is in there, I'd be careful.

Enter'd too soon! Depending on what you're doing, it might be possible/do-able to use something like StackDriver's logging to build a live dashboard, or use a Pub/Sub subscription to update a live view. Depends on your data.